# Performance get bad when mouseChildren is true with flash direct mode in browser IE8 ~ 10

Tags: performance, flash, internet-explorer, fullscreen, displayobject

I have encountered a strange condition which produces bad performance with our `DisplayObject`s.
Here is the situation:

1. We use Stage3D and direct mode for our 3D Flash Web Gaming Project.
2. We use CS6 to build our GUIs for this project. In (and only in) Internet Explorer, the performance becomes bad when the screen is switched from Flash Fullscreen Mode (*not* browser full screen) to Normal Screen Mode.
3. Our Main Game GUI, which is a `DisplayObject`, has many children.

After several tests, I finally found that the performance does *not* get bad when the property `mouseChildren` of Main Game GUI is false *or* without "direct mode".
Given that this situation only happens in Internet Explorer with FlashPlayer's direct mode, is there any way for me to revise my code?

Comment: Checking for mouse interactions can have a large effect on performance. If it's not necessary, you could try setting `mouseEnabled = false` for every child of your Main Game GUI which doesn't need to be interactive.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. But this performance issue only happens on IE with Flash's direct mode, I wonder why other browsers don't have this issue？Is there any one encountered this issue as same as me?

Comment: @陳龍進 IE tends to have issues with Flash for reasons unknown.